# Nivo Slider and fullscreen background: chopped transitions in IE

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, nivo-slider

If I use Nivo Slider on a page with a fullscreen background image, the slide transitions work slow and chopped in IE 7 and 8. In all other browsers, the transitions work smooth.

Here is a very basic example:
http://www.test-case.de/fullscreen-nivo/demo/demo.html

To ensure that the problem is not caused by any JS conflicts, I didn't use any JS for the fullscreen background. It's only a few lines of CSS.

Anybody an idea how to fix that?

Thanks a lot!
Karl

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to partially fix it:

```
img.full-screen-image { -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor; }
```

Not an ideal solution though.